# zend2: website deployement error

Tags: exception, zend-framework2

Im trying to deploy my site, but even after 2 days and lots of searches cannot figure out what causes this error.

```
 Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Config being merged must be an array, implement the Traversable interface, or be an instance of Zend\Config\Config. integer given.' in vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ConfigListener.php:324 Stack trace: 
#0 vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ConfigListener.php(355): Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener->addConfig('config/autoload...', 1) 
#1 vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ConfigListener.php(147): Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener->addConfigByPath('config/autoload...', 'glob_path') 
#2 [internal function]: Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener->onLoadModulesPost(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))  
#3 vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ConfigListener.php on line 324
```

Comment: do you use **composer.phar** ? try to update. Have you the right sub-directories (/config, /config/autoload,...) ? have you all config files ?

Comment: Check your Module.php to make sure all methods such as getAutoloaderConfig() or get*Config() actually return an array, or include a valid config file. Possibly post your code?

Comment: The `StackTrace` leads you to `config/autoload...`  so at least ONE of the files in there is not returning what it's supposed to do (`array`, `traveseable` or `Zend\Cnfig\Config`). Check the files in there.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well and problem was one of my config file was not returning anything. I've made my local.php file empty by accident because it was returning empty array.

Make sure your config files local.php, global.php, module.config.php are returning arrays (even empty).